# How to change the default database driver to the SQLite option in profile installation?

Tags: database, installation-profiles, 10

I have two database driver options in the "database setup" step while installing a Drupal project from a custom profile. By default, the MySQL database is selected.

[image]

But I want it to choose SQLite database as default, like this:

[image]

How can I do that in my custom profile?